# why react-Native does not work ubuntu 20.04

Tags: react-native, ubuntu

When I try to install with `npm` , I get the below console verbiage

```
 guilherme@guilherme-Aspire-A515-52G:~$  npm install -g react-native-cli  npm WARN checkPermissions Missing write access to /usr/local/lib npm ERR! code EACCES npm ERR! syscall access npm ERR! path /usr/local/lib npm ERR! errno -13 npm ERR! Error: EACCES: permission denied, access '/usr/local/lib' npm ERR!  { [Error: EACCES: permission denied, access '/usr/local/lib'] npm ERR!   stack: npm ERR! 'Error: EACCES: permission denied, access \'/usr/local/lib\'', npm ERR!   errno: -13, npm ERR!   code: 'EACCES', npm ERR!   syscall: 'access', npm ERR!   path: '/usr/local/lib' } npm ERR!  npm ERR! The operation was rejected by your operating system. npm ERR! It is likely you do not have the permissions to access this file as the current user npm ERR!  npm ERR! If you believe this might be a permissions issue, please double-check the npm ERR! permissions of the file and its containing directories, or try running npm ERR! the command again as root/Administrator.

npm ERR! A complete log of this run can be found in: npm ERR!     /home/guilherme/.npm/_logs/2020-06-17T23_39_26_149Z-debug.log guilherme@guilherme-Aspire-A515-52G:~$ ^C guilherme@guilherme-Aspire-A515-52G:~$
```

So I try with `yarn` and works but not 100%
Because, this time when I write

```
react-native init myProject
```

I get an error like:

> return command not found!

Any help with this will be appreciated.

Answer (score 1):

Mano, eu uso a cli do expo, e até agora ta me servindo bem, da uma olhada na documentação, é bem simples https://expo.io/learn

Instala a o expo cli :

```
npm install expo-cli --global
```

Cria um projeto :

```
expo init nomeDoSeuApp
```

Entra na pasta :

```
cd nomeDoSeuApp
```

E da um start na servidor :

```
expo start
```

Se estiver usando um simulador android, depois que aparecer o qr code no terminal da um `a` que ele ja inicia o app no seu simulador

---

I'am using the expo cli, and its been serving me pretty well, take a look at the Docs https://expo.io/learn .

First, install it globally :

```
npm install expo-cli --global
```

Create a project :

```
expo init nameOfYourApp
```

Get into the folder :

```
cd nameOfYourApp
```

Start the server :

```
expo start
```

If you are using an android simulator, type `a` after the qr code shows up on the terminal, the app will start automatically on the simulator.